# Tkinter: multiple pages handling with grid geometry manager

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to generate a GUI for setting some parameters in my embedded SW. I can generate the GUI for each module like this, using the **grid** geometry manager:

[image]

Now, I would like to fusion all pages in one, and jump from one module configuration to another by clicking on a button.

[image]

However, I haven t been able to get the proper layout. The solution for multi page handling is using the **pack** geometry manager, so I can t directly merge the 2 solutions (Gui layout AND multi page handling). I have to decide which geometry manager to use first. I would prefere grid, but when I port the multi paging solution, the page's specific buttons are not available anymore (empty page).
When I try the pack solution, I can 't get a way to stack the page specific buttons, so they are available but all on the same row. I checked other solutions, but couldn t find my solution yet. Any help is welcome.

Here is my code for the grid solution, currently running with Python 2.7:

```
import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import *

class Page(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    def show(self):
        self.lift()

class Page1(Page):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Page.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="misalignment")
        label.grid(row=1, columnspan=3)

        ## Buttons definition
        # bool parameter
        input_var9= IntVar()
        label_par9 = tk.Label(self, text= "enabled")
        checkBox_enabled = Checkbutton(self,
                                variable=input_var9,
                                onvalue=1,
                                offvalue=0,
                                )
        label_par9.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=E)
        checkBox_enabled.grid(row=2, column=1)

        # integer parameter
        label_par1 = tk.Label(self, text= "minSpeedStraightDrivingEstimation")
        input_var = tk.DoubleVar(value=0.)
        spin = tk.Spinbox(self, textvariable=input_var, wrap=True, width=8, from_=0, to=100, increment=1)
        slide = tk.Scale(self, variable=input_var, orient='horizontal', length=400)
        label_par1.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=E)
        slide.grid(row=3, column=1)
        spin.grid(row=3, column=2)


class Page2(Page):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Page.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page 2")
        label.grid(row=0, columnspan=3)

class Page3(Page):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Page.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page 3")
        label.grid(row=0, columnspan=3)

class MainView(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        p1 = Page1(self)
        p2 = Page2(self)
        p3 = Page3(self)

        buttonframe = tk.Frame(self)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        buttonframe.grid()
        container.grid()

        p1.place(in_=container, x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        p2.place(in_=container, x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        p3.place(in_=container, x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

        b1 = tk.Button(buttonframe, text="misalignment", command=p1.lift)
        b2 = tk.Button(buttonframe, text="Page 2", command=p2.lift)
        b3 = tk.Button(buttonframe, text="Page 3", command=p3.lift)

        b1.grid(row=0, column=0)
        b2.grid(row=0, column=1)
        b3.grid(row=0, column=2)

        p1.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('Carma parameter client')
    main = MainView(root)

    root.wm_geometry("1000x800")
    root.mainloop()
```

One possibility is that the container frame, which holds the module specific widgets, is not defined properly. It was working with pack, but defined as:

```
buttonframe.pack(side="top", fill="x", expand=False)
container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
```

And now, it is like this:

```
buttonframe.grid()
container.grid()
```

My current hypothesis, is that the container frame is not expanded, hence nothing can be displayed. I tried to add a sticky= S+W+E in its grid definition, but it doesn t work.

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you want. But, I have an answer. do you want to check it out?

Comment: Hi, I have found a way with the pack manager. I am creating frames for each button (composed from 2 or 3 widgets), this way I can force a new line.  but I still have some stuff unclear, like the content is centered middle, whereas I would like it to be centered left. Also, my solution generates a lot of code, so I am not 100% happy with it. If you have something, let me know. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: If you don't mind, what does `lift()` do in your code? Your code was not running for me, I just made it run nothing more.

Comment: This Gui allows me to change the parameters in my SW. The parameters are organized by modules. When I start the GUI, I come in the main window. Per default, the page 1 is displayed. When I click on page 2, I see the parameters belonging to this page/module. The lift method is used as the button command. It hides the content of the current page and shows the content of the newly selected page. How can you switch pages if you dont use it?

Comment: OK, I almost found a solution with the pack geometry manager, but issues are remaining. I will share the solution as soon as all of them are solved. If you have similar troubles, or solution, don t hesitate to contact me.